# Need more disk space for Mongo

Tags: mongodb, memory, disk

I am getting the following exceptions in my Mongo

```
13,08 07:06:06:356 [|||] [ajp-bio-9207-exec-3] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - CommandFailureException occurred when processing request: [POST] /MerchantBridge_stable/saks/importdata
{ "serverUsed" : "10.157.192.16:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "Can't take a write lock while out of disk space" , "code" : 14031}. Stacktrace follows:
com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "10.157.192.16:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "Can't take a write lock while out of disk space" , "code" : 14031}
        at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:76)
        at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:131)
        at com.mongodb.DBCollection.drop(DBCollection.java:1015)
```

I am guessing I need to set something in the mongod.conf file.

Any tips?

Comment: Changing the configuration file will not free up disk space. What exactly don't you understand from this error? It's pretty clear.

Comment: I do see this error when the disk is *not* full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this [guide](http://jorshasaur.us/mongodb-cant-take-a-write-lock-while-out-of-disk-space/) by Josh Barber, you simply need to increase the machine's disk space! Try running `df` in the command line to view the machine's current disk space utilization, you're probably close to 100%.

Another option is to nuke it from orbit! If you're using a VM, you could always scrap it and rebuild. This will require a full rebuild, but that might be easier than trying to repartition your VM's hard drive.

Comment: If it is a VM, why not simply add a virtual hard disk, copy the data over and mount it at the appropriate location?